# Adding reviewers to pull-request by using bitbucket API

Tags: powershell, jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to automate process of merging branches by using Powershell in Jenkins job for our bitbucket repo however it is needed there to get one approval before merge can take place. I successfully made code for checking if branches are different to check if merge is needed by using get method and creating pull-requests also works by using post method however when I am trying to add reviewer I am getting error:

> "Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

I hope the problem I am facing is clear. If there is any more information I should provide I will do it gladly.

I tried to do that in many ways by adding reviewer directly in `Create-PullRequest` function:

```
function Create-PullRequest([string]$Url, [string]$User, [string]$Pass, [string]$Branch, [string]$MergeBranch, [string]$ReviewerUsername) {
  $Headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $Pass)))
  }

  $Body = @{
      title        = "Automated Pull Request - $($Branch) to $($MergeBranch)"
      description  = "This is an automated pull request created by Merge-Branches-MF Jenkins Job."
      fromRef      = @{
          id   = "refs/heads/$Branch"
      }
      toRef        = @{
          id   = "refs/heads/$MergeBranch"
      }
      reviewers    = @(
          @{
              user = @{
                  name = $ReviewerUsername
          }
      }
      )
  }

  $JsonBody = $Body | ConvertTo-Json

  try {
    $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Headers $Headers -Method Post -Body $JsonBody
    $PullRequest = $Response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Output "Pull request created: $($PullRequest.links.self[0].href)"
    return $PullRequest
  } catch {
    Write-Output "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    return $null
  }
}
```

Or by making separate function just to Put reciever to the pr but that was returning the same error.
(while separating functions pr was created successfully however when I combined these functions pr was not created or was created but without reviewer):

```
$ReviewerJson = @"
{
    "user": {
        "name": "techJenkinsUser",
        "emailAddress": "exampleEmail@example.com",
        "id": 1212,
        "displayName": "Tech. Jenkins User",
        "active": true,
        "slug": "techjenkinsuser",
        "type": "NORMAL"
            },
        "role": "REVIEWER",
        "approved": false,
        "status": "UNAPPROVED"
 }
 "@
 $Reviewer = $ReviewerJson | ConvertFrom-Json

function Update-PullRequestWithReviewer([string]$Url, [string]$User, [string]$Pass, $Reviewer) {
  $reviewersArray = @(
    @{
      user = @{
        name        = $Reviewer.user.name
        emailAddress = $Reviewer.user.emailAddress
        slug        = $Reviewer.user.slug
        id          = $Reviewer.user.id
      }
    }
  )
  $reviewersJson = $reviewersArray | ConvertTo-Json

  $Body = @"
{
  "reviewers": $reviewersJson
}
"@

  $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Headers $Headers -Method Post -Body $Body
  return ($Response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer use the username to add reviewers [due to GDPR](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/bitbucket-api-changes-gdpr/#removal-of-usernames-from-user-referencing-apis). You have to use the uuid:

```
"reviewers": [{ "uuid": "{replace_me_with_an_actual_uuid}"}]
```

To get the uuid you need to call [this endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#user-object-and-uuid) with the username and get the UUID from the response.

I'd say that the best option is to first use a tool like Postman to call the update/create url which will be much easier. Then you can get Postman to generate Powershell code which you can then change to match it with your code.

Comment: It seems like it's case for bb API 2.0 I am using 1.0